# How to change Raspberry Pi Bluetooth agent to "NoInputNoOutput" using the python

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I need to change the Raspberry Pi bluetooth agent through the Python script. I was able to change the agent using the command "bluetoothctl --agent NoInputNoOutput" in terminal
When i try to execute the "bluetoothctl --agent NoInputNoOutput" through python it's not executing it be idle

i cnnected the raspberry pi through SSH and executing the command using the below line

ssh_client.executecommand("bluetoothctl --agent NoInputNoOutput")

Any suggestions or any changes to execute the "bluetoothctl --agent NoInputNoOutput" commmand via python

The other bluetooth commands are executing successfully

```
ssh_client.executecommand("bluetoothctl power on")
ssh_client.executecommand("bluetoothctl discoverable on")
ssh_client.executecommand("bluetoothctl pairable on")
```